# SetEnvIf Referer でリファラ値が空になる？

Tags: apache

下記の記述で、レスポンスヘッダにリファラを表示したいと思っています。

```
SetEnvIf Referer "^(.*)" X_REFERE_VALUE=$1
Header set X-Referer "%{X_REFERE_VALUE}e" env=X_REFERE_VALUE
```

ドメインを持つサイト `example.com` のiframe内から呼び出して見たところ、
リファラに値が入りませんでした。

`X-Referer: (空白)`

値に直接Testとしたところ、

```
SetEnvIf Referer "^(.*)" X_REFERE_VALUE=Test
```

`X-Referer: Test`

と表示はされました。

正規表現が間違っているのでしょうか。
ご教授ください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`X_REFERER_VALUE`のスペルミスではありませんか？ (Rが一つ足りない)

Comment: スペルミスが原因でした。ありがとうございます。